# NodeJS Prototype and Requires

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get a basic prototype working with requires, I've looked online at examples but they don't seem to work (Node 4.0.0).

I come from a JAVA background and I'm trying to wrap my head around making objects and static methods for Javascript (I'm aware JavaScript isn't OOP but you can make it 'seem' OOP)

```
//Player.js

var Player = function(name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

//Map<name,Player>
Player.prototype.playersOnline = [];

Player.prototype.getPlayerFromName = function(name) 
{
    if(Player.playersOnline[name] != undefined)
    {
        return Player.playersOnline[name];
    }
    return undefined;
};

module.exports = Player;
```

And the problem

```
//Main app.js
var Player = require('./objects/Player');
Player.getPlayerFromName(name) << TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: You are exporting a function, not an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getPlayerFromName` is included in prototype, thus it is an **instance** method, but you are using it as a **static** method. 
To make methods static, add them to the function object, not the prototype:

```
Player.playersOnline = [];

Player.getPlayerFromName = function(name) 
{
    if(Player.playersOnline[name] != undefined)
    {
        return Player.playersOnline[name];
    }
    return undefined;
};

module.exports = Player;
```

Usage example: http://www.node-console.com/script/httpstackoverflowcomquestions32669672

Note that **instances** won't have these methods.

Comment: The method is still undefined.

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns mm.. that's weird. You sure the path to the `Player.js` is correct? Looks like it is not `require`'d properly.

Comment: But when using 'new' will it put all these functions back into memory?

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns I've made a usage example: http://www.node-console.com/script/httpstackoverflowcomquestions32669672

Answer (score 2):

You got it almost right. `Player` is what you call a "class" in Java. So you need to instantiate it to access its methods.

But if you want to call what resembles a static method, you have two ways:

## 1. Attach the static function to the "constructor":

```
function Player (name) {
    this.name = name;
}

//Map<name,Player>
Player.playersOnline = {};

Player.getPlayerFromName = function(name) {
    if(typeof Player.playersOnline[name] === 'undefined') {
        return Player.playersOnline[name];
    }
    return undefined;
};
```

## 2. Access the function via prototype directly:

function Player (name) {
    this.name = name;
}

//Map
Player.prototype.playersOnline = {};

Player.prototype.getPlayerFromName = function(name) {
    if(typeof Player.prototype.playersOnline[name] === 'undefined') {
        return Player.prototype.playersOnline[name];
    }
    return undefined;
};

**Some notes:**

1. It is better to declare the constructor function rather than use function expressions. [Read more about the difference here.](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/)
2. It is highly recommended to use open curly braces at the end of the line. This is not just some coding style preference, you can actually avoid tricky bugs by doing so. [Read more here](http://encosia.com/in-javascript-curly-brace-placement-matters-an-example/).
3. By the way maps are objects in Javascript not arrays:

   //Map
   Player.prototype.playersOnline = {}; //This will work as intended

Comment: I updated the answer with both ways to achieve your goal plus some notes.

Answer (score 2):

Your need to new a Player object

```
var Player = require('./objects/Player');
var player = new Player();
player.getPlayerFromName(name)
```